# Removing scripts from PDFs using itext5

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext

I am trying to remove all objects in a PDF that might be malicious, using itext. I found out that I have to remove the following objects:

```
PdfName.AA
PdfName.JS
PdfName.JAVASCRIPT
PdfName.OPENACTION
```

What I am currently doing is getting the PdfDictionary of the current page and remove the 4 objects.

```
int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i=0; i < pages; i++) {
  PdfDictionary p = reader.getPageN(i);
  if (p!=null) {
    p.remove(PdfName.AA);
    p.remove(PdfName.JS);
    p.remove(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT);
    p.remove(PdfName.OPENACTION);
  }
}
```

In general that seems not to work. I looked into the internal structure of a PDF and could not find one of these objects on the first level. Do I have to traverse all the other dictionaries that are returned by `p` (recursively)?
I tried to remove `PdfName.ANNOTS` to see if the code is working in general and it is working - all the annotations have been removed.

I hope my question becomes clear. Can someone pls point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're overlooking the fact that there could also be document-level javascript. By looping only over the page dictionaries, you miss possible vulnerabilities (e.g. an Open Action is totally unrelated to a page; it's what happens when you open a document). Why don't you loop over the cross-reference table? See for instance the [RemoveLaunchActions](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-13#497-removelaunchactions.java) example from my book. In your code sample, you don't even remove the most dangerous threat: embedded executables!